# Basic Visual Studio 2013 programming

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The program has to request 3 numbers from an individual, and then return the largest and secondLargest of those numbers. This is what I have:

```
{
    int num1, num2, num3;
    int largest, secondLargest;

    printf("Enter number 1: ");
        scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Enter number 2: ");
        scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("Enter number 2: ");
        scanf("%d",&num3);
        {
    if(num1>num2);
        largest=num1;
        if(num3>num1);
        secondLargest=num1;
            largest=num3;

    printf("The largest number is: %d\n"),largest;
    printf("The second largest number is: %d"),secondLargest;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

**Very Specifically, the output must follow the following format**

Enter number 1: 27

Enter number 2: 36

Enter number 3: 12

The largest number is: 36

The second largest number is: 27

---

When I run the program, it returns insanely large numbers, which leads me to believe I am missing something very simple, or that I have 0 understanding of what is required for even a basic program like this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not coding in Visual Studio, but in C++ ; Visual Studio is perhaps your compiler, you could use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). You should edit your question to improve it: which standard of C++ (i.e. C++11) do you want to use? And you should enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler then use the debugger to run your program step by step. Don't expect us to do your homework

Comment: The `scanf` has buffer overrun possibilities.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c Also, search the internet for "scanf buffer overrun".

Answer (score 3):

Either your code is so badly formatted either you're not familiar with `if` statement. There is no need to put `;` after `if(something)`.

```
if(num1>num2)
    largest=num1;
if(num3>num1) {
    secondLargest=num1;
    largest=num3;
}
```

Moreover, there are two strange curly braces after the last `scanf()` and the last `printf()`.

Comment: A safer coding practice is to always use curly braces, `{ }`, even if there are zero or one statements.

Comment: This was causing me such a headache! Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, are they also requiring the use of `printf`?

```
printf("The largest number is: %d\n"),largest;
printf("The second largest number is: %d"),secondLargest;
```

That's not correct syntax for the function. The format specifiers without arguments is likely injecting garbage.

```
printf("The largest number is: %d\n",largest);
printf("The second largest number is: %d",secondLargest);
```

That's the proper way, but you have other issues as well, but this should fix the output-ing of junk.

Comment: Yes, the requirements of printf is there. I knew I must have missed something simple, so I greatly thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, an if-statement looks like this:

```
if (condition) {
    Do this..
} else {
    Do that...
}
```

The curly braces are optional if only one line should be executed if the condition applies. The else-clause is also optional.

Second, your `printf` calls are wrong. **All** parameters have to be within the parantheses or they won't be compiled as arguments. Also, add a newline to your last `printf` call.

Comment: You guys are WONDERFUL! I am very very new to this, and in the future, will try not to offend these professionals in how I ask for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You used `if` expressions incorrectly. You shall not use `;` end of `if` conditions.
2. You forgot to consider all the situations.
3. You use `printf()` incorrect!

This is part of your code :

```
if(num1>num2);
 largest=num1;
        if(num3>num1);
        secondLargest=num1;
            largest=num3;
```

That is equal to :

```
if(num1>num2)
    {
    }
largest=num1;
if(num3>num1)
    {
    }
secondLargest=num1;
largest=num3
```

So, first you must remove the `;` characters from the end of `if` lines and add `{}` where it is needed (where you want to run more that one line command in `if` expression):

```
if(num1>num2)
    largest=num1;

if(num3>num1)
    {
      secondLargest=num1;
      largest=num3;
    }
```

Is the above code OK? No!

why?

Assume :

`num1=10`,
`num2=15`,
`num3=5`

What happens in this case? Nothing,As `num1<num2` and `num3<num1`The program skip `if` expressions and your `largest` and `secondLargest` variables won't initialized. The value that you see in output is the random value that assigned to them when you defined them.

So you must add all the situations also.

And finally you must use `printf()` as below :

```
printf("The largest number is: %d\n",largest);
```

The final program looks like this:

```
  {
    int num1, num2, num3;
    int largest, secondLargest;

    printf("Enter number 1: ");
        scanf("%d",&num1);

    printf("Enter number 2: ");
        scanf("%d",&num2);

    printf("Enter number 2: ");
        scanf("%d",&num3);


    if(num1>num2)
        {
        largest=num1;
        secondLargest=num2;
        }
    else
        {
        largest=num2;
        secondLargest=num1;
        }

    if(num3>largest)
       {
        secondLargest=largest;
        Largest=num3;
       }
    else
    if (num3>secondLargest)
           secondLargest=num3;

    printf("The largest number is: %d\n",largest);
    printf("The second largest number is: %d",secondLargest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am1r, thank you for your patience and your assistance! I am seeing that I have no understanding of the else statements, as well as proper use of my syntax in various functions.

Comment: @dfwlly You're welcome.Yes, You must use some tutorial I think :) I think this is a good source : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ - and if you received your answer among these answers, you can check the correct answer for future viewers :)